# create folders from a text file

Tags: linux, terminal, macintosh

```
ls -R $pwd  > text.txt
```

The above command generates the below txt file:

```
engagement
groups
solo
text.txt

./engagement:
VAM01427.JPG
_VJR3208.JPG
_VJR3244.JPG
_VJR3281.JPG

./groups:
family
friends

./groups/family:
_VJR3358.JPG
_VJR3376.JPG
_VJR3379.JPG

./groups/friends:
_VJR3404-2.jpg
_VJR3416.jpg
_VJR3456.JPG

./solo:
VAM01381.JPG
VAM01385.JPG
VAM01386.JPG
```

Based on this text file I am trying to create the folders with mkdir command.

When I run the command: `cat text.txt | xargs -L 1 mkdir`
This command is generating duplicate folders

I am unable to frame the question properly..Could someone help?

Comment: Is the overall goal to replicate the directory structure? If so, it would be much easier to use a tool like rsync, without the intermediate text file. This would additionally also handle all possible filenames, not just names that the ls utility happens to write correctly on single lines.

Comment: Your list mentions nothing of the file/dir permissions.

Comment: @Kusalananda we are trying to simplify folder creations for photographers and customers. Upon sending the text file by customer to photographer. Photographer can replicate the folder structure based on text file. In case of rsync: customer needs to provide credentials, which I dont think they will be comfortable to share

Comment: "_In case of rsync: customer needs to provide credentials_" - why would they need to do that?

Comment: Do the tags mean that you're running a Linux-base OS on an Apple Macintosh, replacing the macos operating system (using [XNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU) as its kernel rather than Linux)  that would have come with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your text file, i've been able to do what you want (creating directory in $HOME Folder) with this `cat text.txt | grep ./ | awk -F: '{ print $1}' | xargs -L 1 mkdir` so we first filter the ./ lines and then remove the : at the end to create the folders.

Comment: This is working..Thanks

Comment: `grep './'` is probably meant to be `grep '^\./'`

Comment: You can merge the first three commands in your pipeline into a single `awk -F: '/^\.\// {print $1}' text.txt`

Answer (score 3):

If you change the format of the text file to list only directories, the whole problem becomes much simpler:

```
find . -type d >directories.txt
```

Then

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do mkdir -p "$dir"; done <directories.txt
```

Here we assume that directory names might contain spaces, but definitely not newlines

Comment: If you don't want to list directories that does not need to be listed (because `mkdir -p` would be a no-op for these directories), you could use the following to generate a list of leaf-only directories: `find . -type d -links 2`

Comment: Shrug. No reason.